# colspan rowspan in latex

Tags: tables

Hi i am trying to add table like this i tried this code but unable to convert it in exacly like this

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.6in}|p{0.3in}|p{0.9in}|p{0.9in}|p{0.8in}|} \hline 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}} &   
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ }  \\ \cline{3-5} 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}   & S & M & H \\ \cline{1-5} 
\multirow{3}{*}{SOC} & S & S & Z & VS \\ \cline{2-5} 
 & M & M & Z & H \\ \cline{2-5} 
 & H & M & Z & H \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, looking at line 3, I see that you have `\multirow{2}{*}` without specifying the contents of the cell¹. And you didn't put anything into the contents for the `\multicolumn` on line 4, but it's a promising start.

I would do column specifications that reflect the body of the table though, so:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l| c| c| c| c| c| c| c|}
```

(Note you need a letter for each column. Also, I recommend putting a space before the `l`, `r`, `c` or `p` that indicates the column formatting so that you can see what you need to replace when using `\multicolumn`. more easily.)

For the table you showed, there's no need to combine `\multirow` and `\multicolumn` since you're never merging rectangular blocks of cells. The first line would begin with two `\multirow{2}{*}{text}` commands with an `&` between them. To get centering you will need

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\multirowsetup}{}{\centering}
```

to center those headers. Note that the vertical placement of the text in the example is off. `\multirow` assumes that all your rows are single lines when doing its placement. Since the header cells on line two are multi-line, the positioning is half a line short. You can adjust this by using the optional argument between the second and third required arguments:

```
\multirow{c}{*}[-6pt]{Operation}
```

(somewhat counterintuitively, negative values move down and positive values move up but we usually will be moving the text down).

Other than not putting text in your `\multicolumn` commands' second arguments, you've got that down fine as you do the need to use `\cline` between the first and second rows to avoid the line overprinting your `\multicolumn`.

The second row headers will be `p` columns, but we want to center them. For this, I would recommend loading the `array` package to enhance `tabular`. Then we can define a common column type that will give us centered paragraphs:

```
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\centering}p{0.5in}}
```

Then for the header cells, we would write:

```
\multicolumn{1}{H|}{Gas price (in Gwei)}
```

Or, if we wanted to still specify the column widths:²

```
\newcolumntype{H}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}
```

…

```
\multicolumn{1}{H{0.9in}|}{Gas price (in Gwei)}
```

This should be enough to get you to your finished table.

---

1. Somewhat surprisingly, this does not give an error. Instead, it ends up grabbing `\unskip` from the expansion of `\multicolumn` and using that. And now you know.
2. Probably low on the priority list, but it might be a good thing (especially if `array` is ever moved into the kernel) if `\newcolumntype` were replaced (or at least augmented) with a `\NewColumnType` command that follows the syntax of `\NewDocumentCommand`.³
3. Although do we really want the madness of allowing users to write `C*[foo]{bar}[baz]` in their column specifications?

Comment: My `tabularray` package already uses `\NewColumnType` command name. It allows an optional argument at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

A a comprehensive explanation you can find in @Don Hosek answer. Here ar just two "practical" examples, how you can write your table:

1. with use of the `array` and `multirow` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, multirow}

\begin{document}
\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.6in}|p{0.3in}|p{0.9in}|p{0.9in}|p{0.8in}|} 
                           \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ }
        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{ }    \\  \cline{3-5}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ }
        & S & M & H     \\ \cline{1-5}
\multirow{3}{=}{SOC}
    & S & S & Z & VS    \\ \cline{2-5}
    & M & M & Z & H     \\ \cline{2-5}
    & H & M & Z & H     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

(red lines indicate text area borders)

2. with use of the `tabularray` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{tblr}{width=0.915\linewidth,
             colspec = {X[2,l] X[1,l] X[3,l] X[3,l] X[3,l]},
             hlines, vlines
             }
\SetCell[c=2,r=2]{c}
    &   & \SetCell[c=3]{c}     
            &   &       \\
    &   & S & M & H     \\
\SetCell[c=1,r=3]{l} SOC 
    & S & S & Z & VS    \\
    & M & M & Z & H     \\
    & H & M & Z & H     \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

If you like to have the second table example with the same width as has the first one, you can prescribe its width as:

```
\begin{tblr}{width=0.91\linewidth, % <---
             colspec = {X[2,l] X[1,l] X[3,l] X[3,l] X[3,l]},
             hlines, vlines
             }
```

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 6.0 of 2021-08-10).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}[width=0.915\linewidth]{X[2,l] X[1,l] X[3,l] X[3,l] X[3,l]}[hlines, vlines]
\Block{2-2}{}
   &   & \Block{1-3}{}     
           &   &    \\
   &   & S & M & H  \\
\Block[l]{3-1}{SOC} 
   & S & S & Z & VS \\
   & M & M & Z & H  \\
   & H & M & Z & H  \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]